# Is there any chance of data loss or corruption due to mixing of mbr and GPT partition disk in LVM?

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

Virtualization=`VirtualBox`
I did some test locally by adding a physical disk(1 GB)(gpt partitoin table) to a LVM pool(`/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root mounted at "/"`) which had 20GB disk with MBR. The ubuntu 16.04 server also came up without any problem after reboot. Will there be any problem if LVM pool have mix of disks with different `mbr` and `gpt` partition tables in production systems where the volumes of data are large ?

Answer (score 3):

Not a problem. LVM exists to abstract away the unimportant details like a types of partition tables.

If required, it's ok to add them to the same VG and create a single LV over them.